# How can I see the content from react pages? It only shows the files

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set up a React project, but when I try to run my project I only see the overview of the files that I have created on localhost. I've used `npm start` to run the project. I would like to see the content that I have created.

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <title>React Starter</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Index.html

```js
{
  "name": "test2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode development"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.11"
  }
}
```

package.json

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App.js";
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

index.js

[What I see on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IRNI.png)

I want to run the code from my index.js file and see the content from that file. Don't want to see the file structure that is shown in picture 1.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To provide you a better help, it'd be helpful if you could paste your code as snippets rather than images.

Comment: If you are new to react i would suggest looking into create-react-app, this does all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: I tried to use create-react-app now. When I write npm start I get this error: npm ERR! missing script: start. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

To create a project called my-app, run this command:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

If you need more helpful details about  to react project folder structure use this website,

`https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started`